# artisan output one by one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, console, laravel-artisan

If I run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --force` in console everything works as expected.
The output is displayed one by one.

```
Dropped all tables successfully.

Migration table created successfully.

Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

etc.
```

If I run the artisan command from Laravel everything work fine excepting the output. It is displayed once at the end with all of the actions.

```
$this->info('Migrating and seeding the database...');
Artisan::call('migrate:fresh', [
    '--seed'  => true,
    '--force' => true,
]);
$this->line(Artisan::output());
```

I am looking for a method to display Artisan::output() one by one for each table (the same behaviour like running the command in console).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your code works the way it does is that you display the output from the command once it's been completed with:

```
$this->line(Artisan::output());
```

In order to display the output of executed **migrate:fresh** command as it progresses with running the migrations, you need to make it output to the output of the parent command instead of it's own, that's later read by **Artisan::output()**.

The following code will do the trick:

```
$this->info('Migrating and seeding the database...');
Artisan::call('migrate:fresh', [
  '--seed'  => true,
  '--force' => true,
], $this->output);
```

Notice the third argument passed to the `call()` method.